# Javascript - create input button using a string - problem with calling a function onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an input button using a string, and insert it into a div.

My button should include a function which called onclick.
This is how I wrote the code line:

```
document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = '<p>'+details+'</p> <br> <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="edit(`'+dt+'`)"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="remove(`'+dt+'`,'+t+')">';
```

"dialog" is the div id, 'details', 'dt' and 't' are variables.

My problem is with the "Remove" button (the second input on the line).

The "remove" function should get two variables - 'dt' and 't'. It needs to be look like that:

```
<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="remove(dt,t)">
```

But seems like I'm not doing it right with quotes signs (',`,").
I'm getting errors when using the function.

Can anyone identify where I'm wrong here?

Comment: better to use a view library to help you with that, you'll find it's dead simple even if you only need it in a tiny place, such as react or vuejs

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share what error you are getting while using above function?

As of now, I can see you have extra '; as shown below -

```
<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="remove(`'+dt+'`,'+t+')">';
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list note: [ opened at line 1, column 18

Comment: It's weird to get syntax error with ][. Since, we are not using it here anywhere. Try once what @harun-yilmaz suggested. for more understanding between '' vs `` read once https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

You can use backtick (`) and [`${}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax to insert inline variables to the strings:

```
document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = `
     <p>${details}</p> 
     <br>
     <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="edit(${dt})"> 
     <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="remove(${dt},${t})">`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it didn't help.
Actually, the problem with my code and also with yours, was the 't' variable.
The 't' variable is a td.
If I'm removing it, and write only onclick="remove(${dt})" it is working.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand the problem correctly. Can you post the declarations of the variables as well?

Comment: the variable 't' came from another function which creates a table. This is the declaration:

str += '<td class="tdd" onclick="calenderClick(`'+mm+'`,this)">'+month[i1]
[i2]+'</td>';
'this' = td element = 't' at the function I've posted at the post.